# How to create cell editor for speciall cell in grid with another grid and selection of value from it in ExtJs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2, tablecelleditor

I'm trying to create editor with grid and now I have such variant:

```
var panelWithGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: cellEditorGridStore,
    autoScroll: true,
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    sortable: true,
    title: "My Editor",
    ...
    columns: [
        {
            dataIndex: "first",
            width: "13%",
            text: "First"
        },
        {
            dataIndex: "second",
            width: "87%",
            text: "Second"
        }
    ],
    bbar: [
        {
            xtype: "button",
            text: "change value of cell",
            handler: function(){
                //close action + inserting of selected value from one grid to another?
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: "button",
            text: "close editor",
            handler: function(){
                //normal close action? tried to hide, that works bad.
            }
        }
    ]
});
var myOwnCellEditor = Ext.create('Ext.grid.CellEditor', {
    autoCancel: true,
    closeAction: 'hide',
    field: panelWithGrid
});
```

Moreover I created another grid with getEditor attribute in one of all columns

```
...
getEditor: function(record){
    if(record.raw.myColumnIndex==="gridEditor"){
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            ...
            async: false,
            success: function(response, options){
                ...//downloading of cellEditorGridStore
            }
    }
    return myOwnCellEditor;
}
```

So I have a number of problems with such editor. When I click on cell to edit I have an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionext-all.js:38 
Ext.define.startEditext-all.js:38 
Ext.define.showEditorext-all.js:38 
b
```

When I try to hide editor, it isn't shown correct the second time. Do you know a better way to implement such editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found another way to create widget for taking of value from other grid.
I add to my grid

```
listeners: {
    cellclick: function(gridView,htmlElement,columnIndex,dataRecord){
        if(columnIndex == 1){
            if(dataRecord.data.second){
                ...
                //memorize current dataRecord to change value by using of
                //dataRecord.set("second", new_value) and show my grid-editor
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Such decision works quite good, but it's not editor.